# What is the best technique/algorithm to compare trees changes using machine learning?

Tags: tree, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I have a problem I would like to solve using machine learning. I would like to use some sort of classification to know if a just added change in a tree data structure is "good" or is "bad".
Let's say I have this tree:

```
        (A) 
        / \
       /   \
     (B)   (C)
```

And I apply a change to it (a "good" change, so the algorithm should associate this change with the "good" changes). The updated tree would be like this:

```
       (A)
       / \
      /   \
    (D)   (C)
    /
   /
 (B)
```

Added a certain node (D) above another node (B) would be classified as a "good" change.
So when I have the learner with the correct data, the algorithm should be able to know that if I add a node of type D above a node of type B, it is a "good" change.

I would like to work with XML files that keeps the tree structure, a simple classifier like a naive bayes would not work, because it wouldn't be able to recognise if a node is added above another one, it only would be able to know that a node has been added.

I don't know how which algorithm/technique should I use and I don't know how should I pass the data to the learner, because the context in this scenario is important.

I am new to machine learning, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know too much about that topic, but it seems like it would be a good match for [reinforcement learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning).

Comment: [Here](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~gasser/Smarts/learning.html) is another more readable introduction to reinforcement learning.

Comment: I'm not sure if this problem is suited to machine learning or if it is about simple rules. Do you want to classify the tree (change result) or the local change (parent node to child node relation) where the rest of the tree is irrelevant? are there more complicated changes than inserting child nodes? How do you determine whether a tree/change is good/bad?

Comment: I only want to learn from concrete changes like: adding/removing/updating a child but having in mind the local tree context (for example, the nearer N children). The changes can be changing a child content, removing children, adding children, but it is important knowing the local context of the change.
I dont need to worry about if the change is good or bad because I already know it, I have good changes and bad changes lists, that is not a problem. And I want to use ML because I want to process many tree changes and I don't necessary need to know about them. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you want to notify a commenter please use the syntax `@stefan` see [comment reply](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply).

Comment: Your description is still pretty vague. Can you post some code, your tree representation, your good/bad changes samples?

Answer (score 1):

All types of classifiers perform differently in different scenarios: SVM, AdaBoost, RandomForest and even a (naive) Bayesian classifier. Just learn about some libraries for your favorite programming language containing a number of these algorithms and try them.

What matters more are the features you train the classifiers with. In your case,  ...

- depth of the tree
- balance of the tree
- order
- some property of the nodes weighted by the order of these nodes

Comment: But for example using Bayesian classifier I can't pass any of those features you told me. I only can give the algorithm a set of texts that belong to category "good" and another set of text for category "bad". I can't pass tree depth, balance, if the just added node is above a node of type A, B, C, etc...

Comment: @FernandoGarcia Why can't you pass the tree depth or something? It seems you pass the XML file directly to the classifier. I don't think it's appropriate. You need to transform original data to more classifiable features, that's a common and important part in machine learning. It's technically possible to get tree depth by parsing the XML files.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want to avoid, because if I pass the XML to a classifier I am not going to get any good result. I need to handle with the context of the changes done, but I don't know what kind of algorithm should I use for that. I am using apache spark and played with the naive bayesian classifier but... That is not enough for what I want to achieve. Thanks for the reply.